# Excel VBA to pull a cell address from one cell, pull a value from another, and input into yet another cell

Tags: vba, excel

time poster.  I am running Excel 2010 and I've done some VBA stuff, but I'm still kind of a novice, and I've really been spinning my wheels on this one.  So...

My worksheet has these cells — here is what they do (this is hypothetical):

- A1 is blank; it will have something entered later.
- B1 will have a cell address in it — let's say that address is B3. This address will be generated by excel formulas based on what I put into A1 (that part I was able to do).
- C1 will have something it in — let's say the word "hello".

Here is what I need a macro to do, as soon as I put that something into A1 and hit return:

1. Grab the cell address from B1
2. Grab the word "hello" from C1
3. Put the word "hello" into B3
4. Go to A1 and erase its contents, but leave the cell active, and then end

Thanks in advance for any help that can be given on this!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put this inside the code of the specific sheet you want this to work on. When I tested it it went pretty fast, you really don't ever see A1 containing anything. I suppose you could put a wait in there if you wanted to see it. But to put this code in a sheet (just incase you don't know) on the left tree, you'll see VBAProject("workbook name") > Microsoft Excel Objects > Sheet 1 ("worksheet name")

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim keyCell As Range
Dim adr As String, str As String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set keyCell = ws.Range("A1")

If Not Application.Intersect(keyCell, Target) Is Nothing Then
    adr = ws.Range("B1")
    str = ws.Range("C1")

    ws.Range(adr) = str
    With ws.Range("A1")
        .ClearContents
        .Select
    End With
    End
End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That sure did help, but for some reason, it's not activating when I make the entry into A1 — only when I run the macro.  I found a macro one time that had a line something along the lines of... If range("a1") <> "" then | range("b3") = now | What it would do is put the date in B3, every time you put something into A1.  Of course that's just what I can conjure up from memory, but that would run it simply by cell input. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The seems to be a typo in: With ws.Rande("A1"). Try With ws.Range("A1")

Comment: Oh, sorry I guess I miss that, see above for my changes.

Comment: Thanks again, Jason.  Man, for some odd reason, this is still not setting off the macro upon input into A1.  Works if you start the macro manually, but not otherwise.  I'm going to have to go access the workbook where I have this working and see what is different.  I'll update when I find out.  Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put the code? Is it inside a module, workbook, or sheet?

Comment: I put it in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here is what I eventually came up with, and it worked...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        c = Range("b1").Value
        i = Range("c1").Value
            If Target.Value = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Range(c) = i
                Target.Select
                Selection.ClearContents
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I assume (haven't done it) that I could probably embed variables c and i into that line below "else", but for now, this was easier to think through I guess.  I'm not sure why this worked and the others didn't.  For some reason my macros seem...intermittent.

Anyway, thanks again!